llama_index crashes with HuggingFaceEmbedding
I am trying to build a RAG pipeline using llama_index. One of the first steps is to choose an embedding model that will be used for a VectorStoreIndex. My current implementation looks like this:
from llama_index.core import Settings
from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedding

# some other code
if embedding == Embedding.OPENAI:
    Settings.embed_model = OpenAIEmbedding()
elif embedding == Embedding.BGE_SMALL_EN:
    Settings.embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding (
        model_name = "BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5"
    )

While OpenAIEmbedding works as expected, my Jupyter Notebook always crashes when using HuggingFaceEmbedding.
I have simply pip installed all required modules and started running the application. Is there anything else required to make this work? Do I need to download the embedding repository and place it locally? If so, where do I need to place it?

You have to install not just pip install llama-index and pip install openai but also pip install llama-index-embeddings-huggingface.
Alternatively, it is sufficient to install llama-index only, but then you have to adjust your import statement:
from llama_index.legacy.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbedding

As seen in the docs.
